# Blender render black sharp lines with antialias

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, antialiasing

I made a music visualizer for blender, and added a few things. Inside blender I had this:
[image]
I than made a render:
[image]
And if you look close enough you can see that there are some black lines on the edges:
[image]

I tried using different types of anti-alias and different filter sizes.I tried to remove it and this happened 
[image]
Which has too much sharp edges, but removes the black lines around the player. 
Is there a way to remove anti-alias only on some parts? I tried to look on this community but found only for cycles

Comment: A suggestion - try ticking/unticking the "Transparency" box for those objects with the black lines.  This usually occurs with alpha-layered images/planes however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found myself the answer by clicking random buttons and found the answer:
**You have to tick the full sample under anti-alias.**